# MySQL: how to get x number of results per grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

I have a two tables:

1. Items
2. Categories

Each item belongs to a category. What I want to do is select 5 items per category but say 20 items in total.

```
SELECT 

   item_id, item_name, items.catid 

FROM

   items, categories

WHERE

   items.catid = categories.catid

GROUP BY items.catid LIMIT 0,5 //5 per category group
```

Edit: if there are more than 5 items per category - they should be ordered by the item_id (numeric value)

Comment: When there are more than 5 items in a category, what rules should be used to determine ***which*** 5 should be returned?

Comment: @Dems, Good Question: if there are more than 5 items per category - they should be ordered by the item_id (numeric value) and pick the top 5

Comment: I think this is what you want to achieve.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: One of the thousand+ questions about greatest n per group. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=greatest+n+per+group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, catid FROM 
  (SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) cnt FROM items t1
    LEFT JOIN items t2
      ON t2.catid = t1.catid AND t2.item_id <= t1.item_id 
  GROUP BY
    t1.catid, t1.item_id
  ) t
WHERE
  cnt < 6
-- LIMIT 20
```

It will show first 5 items per category. Uncomment `LIMIT 20` if you need. Join `Categories` table if you need.

Comment: reinvented the wheel, and yet not very well, see the elegant six-liner here: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: The page that @Tomas shares a link to talks about choosing the top 'x' per group. However, there is a link on that page that talks about choosing 'x' number from each group. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

Comment: It is working for me but could not understand how. Could you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, catid
FROM (  SELECT item_id, item_name, catid,
            CASE WHEN @catid != catid THEN (@rownum := 1) + !(@catid := catid) ELSE @rownum := $rownum + 1 AS rownum
        FROM (  SELECT item_id, item_name, i.catid
                FROM items AS i
                INNER JOIN categories AS c
                ON i.catid = c.catid
                ORDER BY i.catid ASC) AS h, (SELECT @catid := NULL, @rownum := NULL) AS var
                HAVING rownum <= 5
                LIMIT 20) AS h2
ORDER BY item_id
```

Devart's solution looks right, but I have a bit of a pickle understanding it fully. Mine may not make much more sence to others, but it does to me.

**EDIT:** Understand Devart's solution now, and it is quite brilliant, actually. :)